# How to limit heap size for a c code in linux

Tags: c, linux, memory, memory-management, heap-memory

I wanted to know if it is possible to limit the allocated heap size for a C code which is executing on linux machine.

Is it possible to do so ?

The purpose of doing so is that I am dynamically allocating ~70KBytes of memory and ~20KBytes of stack memory, apart from other globals, and locals. The dynamic allocation is done through malloc().

So in order to confirm that the issue is not with the heap allocation, I want to limit the heap memory of the C code which will be run.

I read few articles online and found that if we use malloc(), memory might be over committed, but if we use calloc(), we will get only usable memory without the over commitment, since calloc() has to initialize the memory block to zeros before giving the pointer. But I do not want use calloc() due to the initialization overhead.

Comment: Are you sure that the tiny `calloc` overhead (which is relevant for small objects only) is worth avoiding it? Did you measure? Large heap zones are often `malloc`-ated (on Linux) thru an `mmap` which will give zeroed memory anyway!

Comment: What is the real issue you are struggling with? Please edit your question to improve it!

Comment: Hi Basile, Thank you for the reply. I am using the C code in an embedded platform and I am getting a crash. The crash looks like a memory issue to a bad address. That is the reason I wanted to limit my C code heap memory and debug on PC platform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use (inside your program) [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html), probably with `RLIMIT_AS` (as cited by [Ouah's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29515982/841108)).

Better yet, make your shell do it. With `bash` it is the `ulimit` builtin.

Be sure that your program is indeed correctly and completely handling `malloc` failure everywhere (testing every return of `malloc` against `NULL` indicating its failure).

If you don't test `malloc`'s result, when it is failing, it gives `NULL` and it is very likely that the next instructions would dereference a null pointer (or some address very close to it), which is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and on Linux giving a [segmentation violation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault).

You probably should consider using [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) during the debugging phase.

BTW, 70Kilobytes of memory is tiny today (at least on Linux laptops, desktops and even tablets). Notice that the [C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) may call `malloc` under the hoods (for example, `fopen` gives a `FILE` handle, which has some buffer, which might be internally obtained thru `malloc`)

And [memory overcommit](http://www.etalabs.net/overcommit.html) can be disabled on Linux with the following command

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory
```

to be run as root.

Comment: u should echo 1 to disable overcommit instead 0

Answer (score 1):

On POSIX systems you can use `setrlimit` function to limit the size of the virtual memory of the process.

From POSIX [documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/stage7tc1/functions/getrlimit.html):

> RLIMIT_AS
>
> This is the maximum size of total available memory of the process, in
>   bytes. If this limit is exceeded, the malloc() and mmap() functions
>   shall fail with errno set to [ENOMEM]. In addition, the automatic
>   stack growth fails with the effects outlined above.