# realloc function gives SIGABRT due to limited heap size

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, malloc, heap-memory

I am trying to reproduc a problem .
My c code giving SIGABRT , i traced it back to this line number :3174
https://elixir.bootlin.com/glibc/glibc-2.27/source/malloc/malloc.c

```
  /* Little security check which won't hurt performance: the allocator
     never wrapps around at the end of the address space.  Therefore
     we can exclude some size values which might appear here by
     accident or by "design" from some intruder.  We need to bypass
     this check for dumped fake mmap chunks from the old main arena
     because the new malloc may provide additional alignment.  */
  if ((__builtin_expect ((uintptr_t) oldp > (uintptr_t) -oldsize, 0)
       || __builtin_expect (misaligned_chunk (oldp), 0))
      && !DUMPED_MAIN_ARENA_CHUNK (oldp))
      malloc_printerr ("realloc(): invalid pointer");
```

My understanding is that when i call calloc function memory get allocated when I call realloc function and try to increase memory area ,heap is not available for some reason giving SIGABRT

My another question is, How can I limit the heap area to some bytes say, 10 bytes to replicate the problem. In stackoverflow RSLIMIT and srlimit is mentioned but no sample code is mentioned. Can you provide sample code where heap size is 10 Bytes ?

Comment: I see the guard as security feature, not about failing to get memory (in such case you get a out of memory error, or a OOM killer). I do not understand why you tag `linux-kernel`. Nothing to do with it. So: are you reallocing a region which were not malloced?(you must give a pointer which was returned by malloc and never freed).

Comment: 10 bytes is basically nothing at all.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi is it possible to replicate SIGABORT ? while doing realloc

Comment: @IanAbbott as a root user we should have control the heapsize of c program to size whatever we want

Comment: Trying giving an illegal pointer. E.g. a already freed block. Pointer from the stack or from static memory. That check is not about memory allocation (and memory allocation is complex, there is own memory, but when it is not enough, glibc will ask operating system to get more memory).

Comment: Strongly most probably you are passing an invalid pointer to `realloc` or your code overwrites internal `*allloc` state (for example by writing out-of-bounds). `heap is not available for some reason giving SIGABRT` Please post the exact error message. Please post an [MCVE]. Why does "giving SIGABRT" means "heap is not available", where is the connection between these two facts? `RSLIMIT or srlimit is mentioned but no problem code is mentioned` I do not understand this sentence. Can you please add more full stops to end/start sentences and make it clearer?

Comment: @KamilCuk added full stop and clarity to what i am asking

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi i created a sample program where i allocated memory by calloc call then i freed it using free then i call realloc passing same pointer ... i didn't get any error ! Strange

Comment: If you are getting an abort from within `realloc`, then with 99.9% certainty the problem is some bug in **your** code, as KamilCuk says - you must have undefined behavior of some kind.  It's not a problem with the internals of `realloc` or with heap size or memory availability or anything like that.  It's a bug in **your** code and since you haven't shown any of your code, we can't help you.

Comment: It is possible to limit heap size, sort of, using the `RLIMIT_DATA` resource for `setrlimit`.  But that is a limit on the memory that the process can allocate from the OS, and calls to `malloc/realloc` may ask for OS memory in different amounts than what you requested.  The limit will also apply to static data and include allocations made from within the library, and it's rounded to the page size.  So you can't get anything as precise as "limit heap to 10 bytes".  In any case, as I mentioned above, I very much doubt that it would help with your problem anyway.

Comment: Your best bet is probably tools like valgrind, AddressSanitizer, etc, which add extra checking on memory accesses and can help localize your bug to where it actually happens, instead of when realloc detects it which may be much later.

Comment: Regarding my statement "10 bytes is basically nothing at all", I mean it is not enough space for the C library functions to implement a heap.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I limit the heap area to some bytes say, 10 bytes
>
> Can you provide sample code where heap size is 10 Bytes ?

From [How to limit heap size for a c code in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29515944/how-to-limit-heap-size-for-a-c-code-in-linux) , you could do:

> You could use (inside your program) setrlimit(2), probably with RLIMIT_AS (as cited by Ouah's answer).

```
#include <sys/resource.h>
int main() {
    setrlimit(RLIMIT_AS, &(struct rlimit){10,10});
}
```

> Better yet, make your shell do it. With bash it is the ulimit builtin.

```
$ ulimit -v 10
$ ./your_program.out
```

> to replicate the problem

Most probably, limiting heap size will result in a different problem related to heap size limit. Most probably it is unrelated, and will not help you to debug the problem. Instead, I would suggest to research address sanitizer and valgrind.